# Could you explain grammar of 'to hook open'?

Tags: grammar, meaning

Could you explain grammar of 'to hook open'? Why not 'to hook to open'?

> She bent her head over the umbrella, lengthened the umbrella somehow,
>   then she reached with the lengthened umbrella to hook open the little
>   train window above her.

Last
by Ali Smith

Comment: She used the point of the umbrella as if it was a hook to move a part of the train window that could be opened and shut.

Comment: I understand that or to push the window hook by the umbrella, but for me it is a strange construction 'to hook open'. I hope someone explain this grammar.

Comment: She may not have used the point, but rather used the handle as a hook.

Comment: You can use 'hook' as a verb to convey the idea of manipulating something with an implement which does not necessarily have a hooked shape. My eraser was jammed in my keyboard but I hooked it out with a pencil. I dropped a gherkin in my soup and hooked it out with a spoon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty common structure in the English language.

Consider these examples:

> he pried open the door of the car to extract the injured guy out of it.

However it's more grammatical to say "pried the door open"

> the polic kicked open the door.

It's more grammatical to say "kicked the door open"

Another example:

> he slammed the door shut

So it is in your example: 
It's more grmmatical to say:

> she hooked the window.. open.

As for the grammar I should say  some English verbs are followed by an object and then an adjective to show the result of an action on the object.

> verb obj adj
>
> verb adj obj

Are both correct but the former seems to be considered more grammatical according to dictionary entries  checked( Cambridge/ Collins/Macmillan)

Comment: What about this "I stepped up and pushed the gate open ... Annoyed, I pushed harder, and stepped through the space I'd wedged open." Why and what 'open' is used here? I mean the second 'open'.

Comment: Hey @Vitaly agian it follows the same structure; as the other answer mentions more technically, these are all resultative constructions. wedge/pry/push/kick/hook + open/shut --

Answer (score 1):

That is a "resultative" construction, where a verb brings about a resulting state.
That state may be represented by an adjective, such as "open".
Here is a link to Wikipedia [resultative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultative).
The relevant section in the Wikipedia article is "Adjectival resultatives".

Comment: With respect,  I'd have to disagree with your point. consider this: "he slammed the door shut* -->  'shut' represents a supplementive clause (verbless adjectival clause) in final position. Hence slam shut is not a phrasal verb. another example : he painted the room green.

Comment: Yes, Fermichem, you are right. "Open" is an adjective, like "shut" and "green", so it's not a prepositional verb.

Comment: Fermichem, thanks for pointing out my error. I think I've found a correct reference in Wikipedia, for "resultative"; I'd like to know what you think of it.

Comment: yes yes ! that's exactly the structure we're looking for! thanks for digging it up !!